# How to install Keras tuner for anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, anaconda

I've tried these commands inside the conda environment that I've created.

`sudo pip install -U keras-tuner`

`sudo pip3 install -U keras-tuner`

and

```
git clone https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner.git
cd keras-tuner
pip install .
```

Still my jupyter notebook shows an error stating:

> No module named kerastuner

Answer (score 1):

I just installed it with: `conda install -n env_name -c conda-forge keras-tuner`

Answer (score 1):

To install this package with conda run **one** of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras-tuner
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 keras-tuner
```

source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras-tuner

Answer (score 0):

Use `import keras_tuner` instead of `import kerastuner`

Answer (score -1):

If you find yourself in need of a PyPI package in Conda then you should write a YAML file and create a new environment using that. This is the best practice recommendation found in "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)". Otherwise, Conda can get rather unstable if you install PyPI packages *ad hoc*. It would be something like:

**environment.yml**

```
name: my_keras_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7         # change this to meet your needs
  - ipykernel          # since you're using Jupyter
  - keras       
  - tensorflow>=2.0.0  # this and below are keras-tuner requirements
  - numpy
  - tabulate
  - terminaltables
  - colorama
  - tqdm
  - requests
  - psutil
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn
  - ...                # add any additional packages you require
  - pip
  - pip:
    - keras-tuner
```

Note the `keras-tuner` requirements are [found in the `setup.py` file](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/1.0.0/setup.py#L32).
Then, to create the environment

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Note that you can use the `--name|-n` flag to provide a different name for the env.

Whenever you need to add additional packages to the env, edit the YAML definition and recreate the env.